# PostgreSQL howto create a group of entries representing a matrix of values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Still a topological base fields are `x`, `y`, `z`, `gradient`, `tmestamp`, `user`
now I am at the problem of populating my base with data. I have several patches that have the same characteristic, but a different position.
I solved it with preparing an insert statement and two nested loops varying the `x`, `y` (`z` being fixed when filling up a strate (at least at the moment).

Programmatical approach is slow, very slow so I tried to play it in SQL and I got that far:

```
insert into topo12 ("x","y","z","gradient","user","refresh")
select generate_series(2,4),generate_series(2,4),1024,12222563,'toto',1234567878;
```

But that doesn't give (logical I know but...) a matrix, but a vector
and so far I am struggling with getting further sub-requests working, so any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is a join, so you can produce a Cartesian product of two series:

```
> SELECT x, y FROM generate_series(1,2) AS x, generate_series(1,2) AS y;
 x | y 
---+---
 1 | 1
 1 | 2
 2 | 1
 2 | 2
(4 rows)
```

You're currently selecting from two set-returning functions at once.  I don't understand what the semantics of that are supposed to be, but it's not producing a Cartesian product of values like you probably want:

```
> SELECT generate_series(1,2), generate_series(1,2);
 generate_series | generate_series 
-----------------+-----------------
               1 |               1
               2 |               2
(2 rows)

> SELECT generate_series(1,2), generate_series(1,3);
 generate_series | generate_series 
-----------------+-----------------
               1 |               1
               2 |               2
               1 |               3
               2 |               1
               1 |               2
               2 |               3
(6 rows)
```

Comment: @bboett The behaviour is undocumented because ['because nobody is very happy
with it and {postgres developers} don't want users relying on it'](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2011-02/msg00056.php). As @Joey says, the safe way is to use a join.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into topo12 ("x","y","z","gradient","user","refresh")
select
    (random() * 2)::int + 2,
    (random() * 2)::int + 2
    ,1024,12222563,'toto',1234567878
from generate_series(1, 10)
```